# How to bind connection to current async context in actix-web

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm currently trying to implement something similar to [DataSourceUtils::doGetConnection](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.java#L101) in rust with actix web.
I've multiple repository traits with methods like `get_user_for_update`. Now currently the implementations of the trait receive an `sqlx::PgPool` and draw a connection from this pool. But in many cases multiple repository methods are called and should execute within one transaction. Is there any way to bind a connection to the current async context in actix web? So each repository method could use the logic "*If there's a connection bound to this thread already, use it. If a transaction is requested, get a connection and bind it to this context, otherwise get a connection, execute, and close it*".

I'd like to avoid passing a connection reference to every repository method, since I'd have to pass it between services too and mocking the connection is really difficult (associated generic types etc).